# Add tab in text sent from Matlab to Word

Tags: vba, matlab, ms-word

I would like to write a string containing a tab in Word from Matlab.
Here is what I have done:

```
word = actxserver('Word.Application'); 
selection=word.Selection; 
selection.TypeText('This document presents the results of ^t my study.')
```

This will not work, it simply displays ^t.
I have also tried to use vbtab instead of ^t, same thing: only displays text.
How can I send a string containing a tab to Word from Matlab?

Comment: The escape character is \ not ^

Comment: It displays it as text too. No matter what I have typed so far, it was not interpreted...

Comment: You can do `selection.TypeText(sprintf('This document presents the results of \t my study.'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `'\t'` does not work, try using `char(9)`:

```
selection.TypeText(['This document presents the results of ',char(9),' my study.'])
```

9 is the ASCII code for the tab character.

Comment: Nice, this solved my problem. Tabs are now properly displayed.